# Modifying a tuple in a vector of tuples c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, tuples

I have a vector of tuples `vector<tuple<int,int>> vector;` and I want to modify one of the tuples it contains.

```
for (std::tuple<int, int> tup : std::vector)
{
    if (get<0>(tup) == k)
    {
        /* change get<1>(tup) to a new value
         * and have that change shown in the vector
         */
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to change the value of the tuple and have the change be reflected in the vector. I have tried using

```
get<1>(tup) = v;
```

but that doesn't change the value of the tuple that is in the vector. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Capture the `tuple` by reference:

```
for (tuple<int, int> &tup : vector){
//                   ^here
    if (get<0>(tup) == k){
        get<1>(tup) = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about that!

Comment: You can also use `auto`: `for (auto& tup : vector) {...}`

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use a reference instead of a value in your for-loop:

```
for (tuple<int, int>& tup : vector){
```